# Set command line arguments in unit tests in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest, command-line-arguments

Is there a possibility to set the command line arguments in unit tests in VS2012?
If not, is there an alternative to test many combinations of such arguments besides writing a batch file?

EDIT:
I have a console program which reads and parses the passed command line arguments.
I would like to assure that the program has the proper behaviour no matter what command line arguments are passed. Instead of trying all combinations over and over again I would like to write a unit test which sets the arguments and starts my program with them.

I don't use any specific test framework. Just the one provided in Visual Studio by creating a new test project.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to test? The Main(..) method of an application?

Comment: Question is not clear. Also this depends on the ability to provide such arguments based on the test framework you use. MSTest, nUnit etc

Comment: `I don't use any specific test framework. Just the one provided in Visual Studio by creating a new test project.` This means you are using MSTest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not extract the parsing logic to a separate class and unit test that separately from your main ()?

The parsing class should receive string parameters. Therefore you can test as many scenarios as you need in different tests without actually having to run the program executable, just calling the class instead.

**UPDATE**:

Now, if you don't want to create an extra class (I would probably still do it, just for clarity, but anyhow), take into account that you CAN just call your static `Main(string[] args)` method from your unit test, passing different parameters to cover different scenarios.

Comment: Good idea, but this would mean to create a separate class only because of the unit tests. My architecture doesn't need a class only for the parsing.

Comment: Updated the answer with more info

Comment: Thank you for the update but the Main method is private per default.

Comment: Well, declare a public method with the code, and call that one from your Main and your test. I'm not seeing what is stopping you from testing it accordingly through unit tests instead of batch files and calling executables.
Or you could declare the method internal, and give access to the unit test assembly through the [InternalsVisibleTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) assembly attribute.

Comment: The thought that changing the access modifier only because of the unit test. I thought this was bad programming style.
But I see that there are no other options than the two mentioned by you. I will decide which one to choose.
Thank you!